# Send data using Socket python

Tags: python, sockets

I was using socket from python to connect.
A simple mechanism is client input an email and received by the server, then the server will process (split the email) and send back the split email to client

this is the client code, the client have to input some email and received by the server

```
import socket

PORT = 1234
IPADDRESS = '127.0.0.1'

def inputEmailServer(IPADDRESS, PORT):
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((IPADDRESS, PORT))
    while True:
        inputEmail = input("Please enter your email : ")
        s.send(inputEmail.encode('utf-8'))
        isi = s.recv(1024)
        print(isi)

while True:
    inputEmailServer(IPADDRESS, PORT)
```

this is server code, the server have to process email sent by the client

```
import socket
import re
import rsa

PORT = 1234
IPADDRESS = '127.0.0.1'

def emailEncrypt(email):
    publicKey, privateKey = rsa.newkeys(512)
    encEmail = rsa.encrypt(email.encode(), publicKey)
    decEmail = rsa.decrypt(encEmail, privateKey).decode()

    print('Email : ', email)
    print('Encrypted email : ', encEmail)

def emailSplit(email):
    username = email.split('@')[0]
    domain = email.split('@')[1]
    domain_name = domain.split('.')[0]
    domain_type = domain.split('.')[1]

    print('Username : ', username)
    print('Domain   : ', domain_name)
    print('Type     : ', domain_type)

def emailInput(inputEmail):
    regex = '^(\w|\.|\_|\-)+[@](\w|\_|\-|\.)+[.]\w{2,3}$'
    
    if len(inputEmail) == 0:
        print("Please enter your email again")
    elif inputEmail.isdigit():
        print("Please enter string")
    elif not re.search(regex, inputEmail):
        print("Invalid email")
    else:
        emailSplit(inputEmail)

def inputServer(IPADDRESS, PORT):
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((IPADDRESS, PORT))
    s.listen(5)
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print ('Socket Up and running with a connection from',addr)
    while True:
        rcvdData = c.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        output = emailInput(rcvdData)
        c.sendall(output)

while True:
    inputServer(IPADDRESS, PORT)
```

But the result is only

```
b''
```

the result must be like this

```
Username :  name
Domain   :  gmail
Type     :  com
```

Can you help me to solve this?
Thank you!

Comment: `b''` 'is the output of the client because the server executed `c.sendall(None)`. For the output you expect, you need to look at the server output.

Answer (score 0):

your code has an error. you miss your return.
below is the fixed code.

[code mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cuzd1.png)

```
import json  # TODO: import json
import socket
import re
import rsa

PORT = 1234
IPADDRESS = '127.0.0.1'


def emailEncrypt(email):
    publicKey, privateKey = rsa.newkeys(512)
    encEmail = rsa.encrypt(email.encode(), publicKey)
    decEmail = rsa.decrypt(encEmail, privateKey).decode()

    print('Email : ', email)
    print('Encrypted email : ', encEmail)


def emailSplit(email):
    username = email.split('@')[0]
    domain = email.split('@')[1]
    domain_name = domain.split('.')[0]
    domain_type = domain.split('.')[1]

    print('Username : ', username)
    print('Domain   : ', domain_name)
    print('Type     : ', domain_type)
    # TODO: need return data
    return json.dumps({"Username": username, "Domain": domain_name, "Type": domain_type}).encode('utf-8')


def emailInput(inputEmail):
    regex = '^(\w|\.|\_|\-)+[@](\w|\_|\-|\.)+[.]\w{2,3}$'

    if len(inputEmail) == 0:
        print("Please enter your email again")
    elif inputEmail.isdigit():
        print("Please enter string")
    elif not re.search(regex, inputEmail):
        print("Invalid email")
    else:
        # TODO: need return data
        # emailSplit(inputEmail)
        return emailSplit(inputEmail)


def inputServer(IPADDRESS, PORT):
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((IPADDRESS, PORT))
    s.listen(5)
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print('Socket Up and running with a connection from', addr)
    while True:
        rcvdData = c.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        print("rcvdData: %s" % rcvdData)  # TODO: debug output
        output = emailInput(rcvdData)
        print("output: %s, type: %s" % (output, type(output)))  # TODO: debug output
        c.sendall(output)


while True:
    inputServer(IPADDRESS, PORT)
```